# why the set $\{(x,y,0) : x^2 +y^2 < 1\}$ is neither open nor closed?

Tags: general-topology

why  the set $\{(x,y,0) : x^2  +y^2  < 1\}$   is neither   open nor  closed ?

My attempt  :  it will not  closed  because  it  is locally compact

i don't  know  how to proved  that it will not open ?

Any hints/solution will be  appreciated

thanks u

Comment: Who says a locally compact set can't be closed? Every compact set is both locally compact and closed.

Comment: The set $S=\{(x,y,0):x^2+y^2\lt1\}$ is not closed because $$\left(\frac12,0,0\right),\left(\frac23,0,0\right),\left(\frac34,0,0\right),\dots,\left(\frac n{n+1},0,0\right),\dots$$ is a sequence of points in $S$ converging to the point $(1,0,0)$ which is not in $S$.

Comment: And it’s not open because *every* neighborhood of the origin contains points not in the set.

Comment: The set $S=\{(x,y,0):x^2+y^2\lt1\}$ is not open because $$(0,0,1),(0,0,1/2),(0,0,1/3),\dots,(0,0,1/n),\dots$$ is a sequence of points outside of $S$ congerging to the point $(0,0,0)$ in $S$.

Comment: Is using *the definition* of open/closed not an option at all? I am frankly baffled why anyone would try and use the concept of locally compact here, when all you need to do is to check the definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $S:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3:z=0,~x^2+y^2<1\}$.

The set is clearly not closed because one can easily produce a sequence in $S$ which converges to a point outside of $S$ (indeed, see bof's comment).

To see why it is not open, consider the definition of an open set. Take a point $(x,y,0)\in S$. Then any open ball of radius $r>0$ around $(x,y,0)$ contains points of the form $(x,y,z)$ where $z>0$, and these points are not in $S$.

Answer (score 1):

I will call the set mentioned in the question $A$.

To show a set is not closed, it suffices to show that a set does not contain all of its limit points. So try to find a point not in $A$ such that all of its neighborhoods intersect $A$.

To show a set is not open, one can show that no basis element is contained within it. Note that basis elements of $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be of the form $(a_1,b_1)\times (a_2,b_2)\times (a_3,b_3)$ where $a_i < b_i$ for $i$ in $\{1, 2, 3\}$.